# Rails uses incorrect version of ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

When I run a rails application, I am running an older version of ruby:

```
[2012-06-04 16:34:29] INFO  ruby 1.8.7 (2010-08-16) [x86_64-linux]
```

I want to run ruby 1.9.2. I have rvm installed with that ruby version selected. Here is the output of rvm list:

```
rvm rubies

=* ruby-1.9.2-p318 [ x86_64 ]
   ruby-1.9.3-p125 [ x86_64 ]
```

It's not working, though. Here is my PATH:

```
/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/home/charlie/.rvm/bin:/var/lib/gems/1.8/bin/:/usr/local/bin/:/usr/local/rvm/lib/:/vendor/bundle/
```

Here is my .bashrc:

```
PATH=$PATH:$HOME/.rvm/bin # Add RVM to PATH for scripting
PATH="${PATH}:/var/lib/gems/1.8/bin/"
PATH="${PATH}:/usr/local/bin/"
PATH="${PATH}:/usr/local/rvm/lib/"
PATH="${PATH}:/vendor/bundle/"
```

Comment: I wouldn't be fiddly with the path like that - the only thing you need in your bashrc is `[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm"`

Comment: Hi, I'm new to UNIX. What does that do?

Comment: That lets rvm setup the path for you (which would yield something different to the $PATH you currently have)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming you're trying to run the development server, is that right? You can create a `.rvmrc` inside your Rails app root folder:

```
rvm use 1.9.2-p318
```

This way, everytime you `cd` into your Rails app, you'll have the right environment loaded. You may also consider creating a gemset for the project.